# Chaining Linq Where clauses

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How would you chain ‘Where’ clauses in linq according to different variable states.
E,g ; checkboxes for age ranges (21-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60 , 60 >)

We have a `List<People>` ‘People’ , and we need to filter it according to checked boxes. Assuming the List cannot be just an IEnumerable as it has been evaluated

Apart from doing this:

```
List<People> filteredPeople = new List<people>();
if(CB1.checked)
    filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Union(People.Where(inTheirTwenties))  //assuming method  inTheir20s filters correct  
if(CB2.checked)
    filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Union(People.Where(inTheirThirties)) ;
//...and so on
```

is there a better way around this?

Comment: Why `Union`? You can directly apply the `Where` method `filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(p => p.Age >=21 && p.Age <=30)`

Comment: A list implements an `IEnumerable`, in fact there are very view collections that don't. So it can and is whether it has been evaluated or not. Are you thinking of `IQueryable`

Comment: This code is just broken. Checking both CB1 and CB2 will NOT return both 20s and 30s. Since you are changing `filteredPeople` between the calls. In fact your code currently returns ALL of `People` regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would bundle this all up into one `Where` statement and update the `inTheirTwenties` methods to take the individual person like this:

```
filteredPeople.Where(x => (CB1.checked && inTheirTwenties(x)) 
|| (CB2.checked && inTheirThirties(x)) ...);
```

Comment: This wont work if we can check multiple check boxes?

Comment: @tichra It should do as we are only evaluating one object at a time by passing the x into the inTheirTwenties method and we are combining the different checks with `||`s

Comment: thanks, and if nothing is checked i assume it will return empty rather than all ?

Comment: @tichra That's correct, you could add a check for `|| (!CB1.checked && !CB2.checked ...)` if you wanted to return all of them if none were checked.

Comment: what according to you would be the best way to return all apart from writing a separate if statement in a preceding line?

Comment: @tichra just finished editing the above comment. You could add `|| (!CB1.checked && !CB2.checked ...)` to the end of the `Where` clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90976/discussion-between-tichra-and-tomdoescode).

Answer (score 2):

Chaining an unknown number of `.Where()` clauses that use `OR` can result in verbose and difficult to read code.  Luckily, in your scenario, you could invert this to a series of `AND` expressions which presents a much more readable batch of code.

```
var filteredPeople = new List<Person>();

if(!checkBox1) filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(p => !inTheirTwenties(p));
if(!checkBox2) filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(p => !inTheirThirties(p));
```

Were this a LINQ-to-SQL query this type of code would also simplify what goes across to a database by making an elegant WHERE clause without a number of `true` and `false` being sent across the wire. Of course you wouldn't be able to use `inTheirTwenties(Person)` to access SQL Server, but instead would do something like:

```
filteredPeople.Where(p => !(p.Age >= 21 && p.Age <=30));
```